# Select only one onchange event of Fileupload

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, file-upload

I have an asp.net page with master page. I have a fileupload control on child(having master page) page. I am using  jquery's change event for fileupload on child page. now i want to disable fileupload control for some reasons from master page. so i am using this script.

```
 function blockFileUpload() {
                $('input[type=file]').change(function () {
                    $('input[type=file]').val('');
                    alert("You Can Not Upload File. Files Storage (50 MB) Limit Reached. ");
                    $('input[type=file]').preventDefault();
                    return false;
                });
            }
```

Now when file upload change event is called both event work simultaneously. so how can i disable child page's change event and hook only master page's onchange event.

Thanx in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Unbind all your change events first and then assign your new change event. For eg:

```
function blockFileUpload() {
                $('input[type=file]').unbind('change');
                $('input[type=file]').change(function () {
                    $('input[type=file]').val('');
                    alert("You Can Not Upload File. Files Storage (50 MB) Limit Reached. ");
                    $('input[type=file]').preventDefault();
                    return false;
                });
            }
```

The code `$('input[type=file]').unbind('change');` unbinds all the `change` event related to the file inputs.

Comment: the same i have tried but not working for me beacuse this function is called first in master page and then in content page onchnage event bounds again

Comment: Have a global variable say `IsBlockFileUpload` and set it to `false` by default in master page. And while calling `blockFileUpload` function set it to `true`. In your child page, wrap the `change` event in a `if` loop checking for `IsBlockFileUpload` , if its `true` then skip binding event else bind the event in child page.